# Can't locate column headers in ColdFusion Reports

Tags: report, coldfusion-10

I've been given an existing application to work on which uses ColdFusion as a service.  I'm a beginner with ColdFusion, however most of it I've been able to figure out.  Now, I've been given a task to edit some existing reports and for some reason I'm having trouble determining where the headers for the columns are located.  The .cfc file that the report URL calls looks like this:

```
 <cffunction
            name="report"
            access="remote"
            hint="Generate a Report"
            output="true"
            roles="view"
            >

            <cfset report = this.reportGenerate(argumentCollection=arguments)/>
            <cfcontent variable="#report#" type="application/pdf" reset="Yes">

        </cffunction>

        <cffunction
            name="reportGenerate"
            access="package"
            hint="Generate a Report"
            output="false"
            returntype="binary" 

etc.
```

I have .cfr files in the application but I don't have Report Builder and have no way to edit them.  I see where the data is being generated but I can't determine where the column headers are defined (at least in this case).  The report URL just calls the .cfc file (a portion of which is shown above).  Can anyone clue me in as to where the column headers might be defined?

Thanks so much,

Pete

Comment: I never used the report builder but you can download it here: https://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html#cf2016devtools (look for ColdFusion 10 Report Builder)

Comment: This report uses the <cfcontent> tag but I don't see how the headers are specified in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling the .CFR reports using the CFREPORT coldfusion tag.

And you need to install ColdFusion Report Builder tool to have a look of the Columns defined.

These Columns are dragged and dropped in the ColdFusion Report Builder tool.
And saved there as .CFR file.

This .CFR file needs to be invoked using the CFREPORT tag.
Query objects from CFC can be passed to the CF report Builder from where these values can be pasted at the tool.

Also parameters can be passed to the .CFR file.